# Is there an easy way to load many units into many overlords?

Tags: starcraft-2

The only way I can find to load a very large number of units into a big ball of overlords (who have been upgraded to carry passengers) is to select all my units, then shift right-click each overlord one at a time.

This is slow, and error prone.  Is there a way to do the whole operation in bulk, with just 2 or 3 clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Bad news for you Travis, what you acutally do is one of the fastest way. If you box your units first and bind them to a key you can simply take these units and right click the ovie.
That's what I do, and it's faster than letting all units run to the first overlord until it's full than to the second.

See here : [fastest way to load overlords](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2030065585)